# Finding the Distance Between Several Points- Lat/Long

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a large table with pickup and dropoff lat/long data. This table has several hundred thousand records, and I want to find the distance between each pickup and dropoff.

Can this be done using SQL in BigQuery?

Comment: Distance from a single base point, or sequenced, or Traveling Salesman Problem?

Comment: Not from a single base point. This has to do with a driver and the trips he does in a day. So he has various pickup and dropoff GPS coordinates depending on the distance between the previous dropoff and next pickup.

Comment: Theoretically - you can do A LOT with BigQuery!! How practically it is possible or not  - depends on specifics  - provide more details on your challenge and we will try to help

Comment: So each record has a car number, pickup lat, pickup long, dropoff lat, dropoff long. I want to know the distance between the pickup lat/long and dropoff lat/long in each record as well as the distance between the dropoff lat/long in the previous record and the pickup lat/long in the next record.

Comment: Yes, can be done in BigQuery. provide some sample data (just few rows)

Comment: For some reason, I cannot enter a table. But mine looks a lot like this, just replace the "trip distance" with "driver number"      http://dracodoc.github.io/2016/01/31/data-cleaning/long_distance_in_short_time.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below, should be good start for you

```
SELECT 
  orderid, 
  car_number, 
  ROUND(distance) AS distance, 
  ROUND(next_distance) AS next_distance
FROM JS(
  (
  // input table
  SELECT
    orderid,
    car_number,
    pickup_lon, 
    pickup_lat, 
    dropoff_lon, 
    dropoff_lat,
    LEAD(pickup_lon) OVER(PARTITION BY car_number ORDER BY orderid) AS next_pickup_lon,
    LEAD(pickup_lat) OVER(PARTITION BY car_number ORDER BY orderid) AS next_pickup_lat
  FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS orderid, 1 AS car_number, -121.23200000000001 AS pickup_lon, 38.1964 AS pickup_lat, -117.48 AS dropoff_lon, 34.5894 AS dropoff_lat ),
    (SELECT 2 AS orderid, 1 AS car_number, -118.76 AS pickup_lon, 34.1445 AS pickup_lat, -122.26 AS dropoff_lon, 37.7606 AS dropoff_lat), 
    (SELECT 3 AS orderid, 2 AS car_number, -117.736 AS pickup_lon, 33.5761 AS pickup_lat, -117.19333333333333 AS dropoff_lon, 34.47484444444444 AS dropoff_lat)      
  ) ,
// input columns
orderid, car_number, pickup_lon, pickup_lat, dropoff_lon, dropoff_lat, next_pickup_lon, next_pickup_lat,
// output schema
"[{name: 'orderid', type: 'integer'},
{name: 'car_number', type: 'integer'},
{name: 'distance', type: 'float'},
{name: 'next_distance', type: 'float'}]",
// function
"function(r, emit){

  emit({
    orderid: r.orderid, car_number: r.car_number, 
    distance: dist(r.pickup_lon, r.pickup_lat, r.dropoff_lon, r.dropoff_lat),
    next_distance: dist(r.dropoff_lon, r.dropoff_lat, r.next_pickup_lon, r.next_pickup_lat)
    });

  function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI/180)
  }

  function dist(pickup_lon, pickup_lat, dropoff_lon, dropoff_lat) {
    var R = 3959; // Radius of the earth in miles
    var dLat = deg2rad(dropoff_lat-pickup_lat);  
    var dLon = deg2rad(dropoff_lon-pickup_lon); 
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
      Math.cos(deg2rad(pickup_lat)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(dropoff_lat)) * 
      Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    var c = 2 * R * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    return c;
  }

}"
)
```

result is :

```
orderid car_number  distance    next_distance    
1       1           325.0       79.0     
2       1           317.0       NaN  
3       2            69.0       NaN
```

> From comments: My table schema is as such:

```
car_number     (string)
pu_datetime    (timestamp)
do_datetime    (timestamp)
pu_lat         (float) 
pu_long        (float) 
do_lat         (float) 
do_long        (float)
```

> Added to match your table schema

```
SELECT 
  pu_datetime, 
  car_number, 
  ROUND(distance) AS distance, 
  ROUND(next_distance) AS next_distance
FROM JS(
  (
  // input table
  SELECT
    pu_datetime,
    car_number,
    pu_lon, 
    pu_lat, 
    do_lon, 
    do_lat,
    LEAD(pu_lon) OVER(PARTITION BY car_number ORDER BY pu_datetime) AS next_pu_lon,
    LEAD(pu_lat) OVER(PARTITION BY car_number ORDER BY pu_datetime) AS next_pu_lat
  FROM 
    (SELECT timestamp('2016-07-01 13:00:00') AS pu_datetime, '1' AS car_number, -121.23200000000001 AS pu_lon, 38.1964 AS pu_lat, -117.48 AS do_lon, 34.5894 AS do_lat ),
    (SELECT timestamp('2016-07-02 10:00:00') AS pu_datetime, '1' AS car_number, -118.76 AS pu_lon, 34.1445 AS pu_lat, -122.26 AS do_lon, 37.7606 AS do_lat), 
    (SELECT timestamp('2016-07-03 11:00:00') AS pu_datetime, '2' AS car_number, -117.736 AS pu_lon, 33.5761 AS pu_lat, -117.19333333333333 AS do_lon, 34.47484444444444 AS do_lat)      
  ) ,
// input columns
pu_datetime, car_number, pu_lon, pu_lat, do_lon, do_lat, next_pu_lon, next_pu_lat,
// output schema
"[{name: 'pu_datetime', type: 'timestamp'},
{name: 'car_number', type: 'string'},
{name: 'distance', type: 'float'},
{name: 'next_distance', type: 'float'}]",
// function
"function(r, emit){

  emit({
    pu_datetime: r.pu_datetime, car_number: r.car_number, 
    distance: dist(r.pu_lon, r.pu_lat, r.do_lon, r.do_lat),
    next_distance: dist(r.do_lon, r.do_lat, r.next_pu_lon, r.next_pu_lat)
    });

  function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI/180)
  }

  function dist(pu_lon, pu_lat, do_lon, do_lat) {
    var R = 3959; // Radius of the earth in miles
    var dLat = deg2rad(do_lat-pu_lat);  
    var dLon = deg2rad(do_lon-pu_lon); 
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
      Math.cos(deg2rad(pu_lat)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(do_lat)) * 
      Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    var c = 2 * R * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    return c;
  }

}"
)
```

Comment: Can this be done without specifying the exact lat/long in the SQL and referencing the whole table instead? I have a pretty big table.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work in BigQuery- BigQuery doesn't have the "output schema" function available.

Comment: Okay, just ran it as is, and it works. When I reference the table stored in BigQuery, it seems to fail. Additionally, the table I am querying has no unique identifier.

Comment: so either adjust code to match your table's schema - or provide your schema - so i will help when time allows!

Comment: My table schema is as such:

- car_number (string)
- pu_datetime (timestamp)
- do_datetime (timestamp)
- pu_lat (float)
- pu_long (float)
- do_lat (float)
- do_long (float)

Comment: just added query to match your table schema

Answer (score 0):

This function will calculate miles between two points.   THIS IS NOT DRIVING DISTANCE.  You would have to use the Google API for that, and I believe there is a limit of 2500 hits per day.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE Function [dbo].[udf-Geo-CalcMiles] (@Long1 float,@Lat1 float,@Long2 float,@Lat2 Float)  
Returns Float as  
Begin 
   Declare @Miles Float
   Set @Miles = 0
   Set @Miles = (Sin(Radians(@Lat1)) * Sin(Radians(@Lat2))) + (Cos(Radians(@Lat1)) * Cos(Radians(@Lat2)) * Cos(Radians(@Long2) - Radians(@Long1)))
   Return Case When @Miles =0 then 0 else abs((3958.75 * Atan(Sqrt(1 - power(@Miles, 2)) / @Miles))) end
End
```

So for example

```
;with cteBase as (
   Select Top 10 
          Box_Nr
         ,From_Lat=Box_Lat
         ,From_Lng=Box_Lng
         ,To_Lat = Lead(Box_Lat,1) over (Order By Box_Nr)
         ,To_Lng = Lead(Box_Lng,1) over (Order By Box_Nr)
    from [dbo].[USPS-Collection-Point] Order by Box_Nr
)
Select * 
      ,Distance = [dbo].[udf-Geo-CalcMiles] (From_Lng,From_Lat,To_Lng,To_Lat)  
 From cteBase
```

Returns

```
Box_Nr  From_Lat    From_Lng    To_Lat      To_Lng      Distance
1       41.6947535  -71.1394048 41.6980289  -71.1341529 0.353027299635122
2       41.6980289  -71.1341529 41.682761   -71.124812  1.15978643547294
3       41.682761   -71.124812  41.7051854  -71.1477813 1.95061187457874
4       41.7051854  -71.1477813 41.7080851  -71.1441519 0.274205428604983
5       41.7080851  -71.1441519 41.702242   -71.1282279 0.915266219941071
6       41.702242   -71.1282279 41.711085   -71.142123  0.941821767229312
7       41.711085   -71.142123  41.7055301  -71.1516977 0.625473329587972
8       41.7055301  -71.1516977 41.7071749  -71.1513423 0.115113681673717
9       41.7071749  -71.1513423 41.7079604  -71.1543306 0.163416766676813
10      41.7079604  -71.1543306 41.667808   -71.154372  2.77425950023261
```